# Putting a break in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I get python to add a break in the middle of the list comprehension?
The question is to take the list of RNA nucleotides and return a list of codons using list comprehension.
I have the following code:

```
import random
bases=["U", "A", "C", "G"]
b1=[random.choice(bases) for i in bases [0:3] '\n' for i in range(0,64)]
print(b1)
```

What I want to do is print 3 choices from bases in one list 63 times. How else can I do that?

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Create the list (or some alternate structure), and then insert newlines where appropriate when you print it out. Don't conflate the two.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this.

```
b1=[[random.choices(bases) for _ in range(3)] for i in range(0,64)]
print(b1)
```

I guess this get's your job done.

this will return the output list of option with sub-list of choices.

```
[['G', 'U', 'C'], ['U', 'U', 'C'], ['A', 'A', 'G'], ['G', 'G', 'U'], ['A', 'A', 'A'], ['U', 'U', 'A'], ['C', 'A', 'A'], ['G', 'A', 'U'], ['G', 'A', 'G'], ['A', 'G', 'G'], ['A', 'A', 'C'], ['C', 'U', 'C'], ['U', 'U', 'A'], ['G', 'U', 'U'], ['U', 'A', 'A'], ['U', 'U', 'U'], ['U', 'C', 'G'], ['G', 'A', 'C'], ['G', 'A', 'U'], ['G', 'C', 'A'], ['U', 'U', 'U'], ['C', 'G', 'G'], ['U', 'A', 'U'], ['U', 'U', 'A'], ['A', 'U', 'C'], ['C', 'G', 'G'], ['C', 'G', 'G'], ['U', 'U', 'U'], ['U', 'A', 'U'], ['G', 'G', 'A'], ['U', 'C', 'G'], ['G', 'C', 'C'], ['G', 'U', 'C'], ['G', 'A', 'A'], ['A', 'C', 'U'], ['G', 'C', 'C'], ['G', 'A', 'U'], ['A', 'G', 'A'], ['G', 'G', 'C'], ['G', 'A', 'C'], ['C', 'A', 'A'], ['U', 'C', 'C'], ['C', 'C', 'G'], ['C', 'C', 'C'], ['G', 'A', 'A'], ['U', 'U', 'G'], ['C', 'C', 'G'], ['A', 'C', 'U'], ['C', 'G', 'C'], ['U', 'G', 'C'], ['G', 'A', 'C'], ['U', 'C', 'A'], ['G', 'A', 'U'], ['C', 'A', 'U'], ['U', 'U', 'C'], ['G', 'A', 'G'], ['C', 'U', 'A'], ['A', 'G', 'G'], ['A', 'G', 'U'], ['G', 'C', 'G'], ['C', 'G', 'U'], ['G', 'A', 'U'], ['G', 'A', 'A'], ['U', 'A', 'U']]
```

Comment: This is good, but note your inner list can be a comprehension as well!

Comment: we can use a tuple instead.
(random.choice(bases), random.choice(bases), random.choice(bases))

Comment: I meant something like `[random.choices(bases) for _ in range(3)]` - this is more scalable in case 3 becomes 300.

Comment: yeah, I could have done that please update the answer. cheers!